# Vuex - dynamic namespaces in binding helpers (mapState, ...)

Tags: vuex

I am registering vuex store modules dynamically

`store.registerModule('home.grid', GridStore)`

then in the component :

```
export default {
name: 'GridComponent',

props: {
  namespace: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

 computed: {
    ...mapState(this.namespace, ['filter']) // doesn't work
    filter() { // more verbose but working
      return this.$store.state[this.namespace].filter
    }
 }
 ...
```

But I got the error :

> Cannot read property 'namespace' of undefined

Any idea ?

question originally asked from "gabaum10" here https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-dynamic-namespaces-in-mapstate-mapactions/28508

Comment: gabaum10 seems to have also found answer in that same thread. Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved here https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/863#issuecomment-329510765

```
{
  props: ['namespace'],

  computed: mapState({
    state (state) {
      return state[this.namespace]
    },
    someGetter (state, getters) {
      return getters[this.namespace + '/someGetter']
    }
  }),

  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      someAction (dispatch, payload) {
        return dispatch(this.namespace + '/someAction', payload)
      }
    }),
    ...mapMutations({
      someMutation (commit, payload) {
        return commit(this.namespace + '/someMutation', payload)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it documented anywhere? Can not find that `getters` thing in their API Reference (which is pretty terrible btw).

Answer (score 1):

One other approach for this might be by taking advantage of the fact that the computed properties are initialized after the data properties. This will only work with computed properties though - as the methods are computed before the data.

An example:

```
export default {
  props: {
    namespace: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
  },
  data(){
    // Append more computed properties before they are initialized.
    this.$options.computed = {
      ...this.$options.computed,
      ...mapState(this.namespace, ['filter'])
    }

    return {
      foo: bar
    }
  },

}
```

Comment: Is this known to work? I get an error: `[vuex] mapActions: mapper parameter must be either an Array or an Object`

Comment: oh right. that's what i've been messing up. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I basically run into the exact same problem with making dynamic getters, for some reason you can't do the vuex map functions with data variables from a component.

So this didn't work for me

```
 ...mapGetters( this.layout,['getFilterByObject'])
```

But I could do this

```
this.$store.getters[this.layout + '/getFilterByObject'](filterGroup)
```

Maybe you can do sth. similar with your state, I didn't test it though

```
this.$store.state[this.namespace].filter
```

Comment: yes it works great without any binding helpers (mapState, mapMutations) : `this.$store.state[this.namespace].filter`. But it makes the code more verbose !

Comment: yes you're right, thanks for sharing your solution! I wish the vuex docs were a little bit more detailed.