# Vuex: 'this' is undefined in mapState

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to map state of dynamic module, but it seems that I don't have access to `this` inside `mapState` or `mapActions`

```js
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';
import MachineModule from '../store/modules/machine';

export default {
  props: {
    machineName: String,
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.registerModule(this.machineName, MachineModule);
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(this.machineName, ['timesServiced']),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(this.machineName, ['serviceMachine']),
  },
};
</script>
```

I got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'machineName' of undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuex - dynamic namespaces in binding helpers (mapState, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55927452/vuex-dynamic-namespaces-in-binding-helpers-mapstate).   There is a github issue linked in the first answer discussing the same issue and workarounds.

Comment: @StevenB. I'm not sure how this would solve this problem. The example is not clear for me.